# Xerox Workcentre 3220 Drivers

Tags: drivers, printing

We just got a Xerox Workcentre 3220 in the office (yay nobody looked up linux compatibility when ordering), and the 3119 drivers keep showing "out of paper" when trying to print.

Any ideas how to set this one up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the xerox windows .zip drivers. Unzip it and get the .ppd driver descriptor out of it.
2. Find a network printer (the printer will have an ip and port, use those), for the driver use the .ppd file.
3. Change the printer settings and change the URI from socket://ip:port to http://ip:port

Answer (score 3):

WorkCentre 3210/3220 Multifunction Laser Printer

The product brochure said :

PCL® 6 and PCL®5e emulations (host-based for Mac and Linux)

**Print Drivers**
Windows® XP (32/64 bit)/Vista/2003 Server/2008 Server, Mac OS®
X version 10.3 and above; Various Linux® OS (via USB interface
only) including Red Hat® 8-9, FedoraTM Core 1-4, Mandrake®
9.2-10.1, SUSE® 8.2-9.2, Mandriva 2005/2006/2007 (32/64 bit),
Ubuntu 6.06-7.04, Debian 3.1-4.0, UNIX AT&T system V (4.2)
BSD4.3, HP-UX (Rel 9x & 10x), SCO 5.x, SUN OS 5.5, Sparc or
Solaris 2.5; Xerox Global Print DriverTM; Xerox Mobile Express DriverTM
(WorkCentre 3220)

have a look of this : [here](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-3210-3220/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en)

you have Drivers wc3220 linux drivers and firmware WC 3220 Firmware version 2.50.00.95 and instructions inside.

**Caution:** These drivers require minimum firmware version of 2.50.00.95.
Firmware version 2.50.00.95 and higher requires use of these drivers.

```
1.- right click on the file you download and extract here. 
2.- open a terminal
3.- navigate /media/XEROX_MFP/Linux
4.- chmod +x ./install.sh
5.- sudo ./install.sh
```

there is an uninstall procedure uninstall.sh and a check_installation.sh

have a look of this file Installer.html in this directory

Comment: What the deuce? I could not find this. Damn. O well... I went with a slightly different solution which involved a bit of a roundabout methodology. I'm gonna check this out as it might install the nifty scanner and fax drivers. In either case I have no idea how I missed it.

Comment: This does not work since it can't find the network printer. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested with this model, but the answer given by [hhlp](https://askubuntu.com/users/3550/hhlp) worked with [WorkCentre 6605DN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472890/xerox-workcentre-6605-drivers) for Ubuntu 15.04.

Just follow his procedure (or the one I reference) and then launch

```
sudo xeroxprtmgr
```

and create your printer via this interface. It will appears in the system now.