# Xerox Workcentre 6605 drivers

Tags: drivers, printing, xerox

I am searching for xerox workcentre 6605 drivers to get our office printer to work in various ubuntu versions, but mainly 13.04.

Do you have any idea of how to do it?

I have been researching this.

I tried [this](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-6605/file-download/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en&contentId=122349&from=downloads&viewArchived=false) without luck, I saw [this](http://foo2hbpl.rkkda.com/) but no luck (the printer is not supported) and more of the same here

How did you got it working?

Thanks you sooo much for your help :)
It´s really apreciated.

Comment: 13.04 is EOL. Please upgrade to 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I just update to ubuntu 14.04 and didn´t work.
Does anyone have an idea of how to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the model Xerox-Workcenter-6605DN. The printer could be installed using the driver for the newer model Xerox WorkCenter 7228 which is included in Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 1):

cold case but could be useful for others. This post is a copy of [my tutorial (in french)](http://wiki.esprit-libre-conseil.com/index.php?title=Imprimante#Xerox). This has been tested on Ubuntu 15.04.

I solved this problem using Xerox drivers.

1. So download them [on their website](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-6605/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux).
2. Add execution rigths to this sh script :

   ```
   chmod +x Xeroxv5Pkg-Debianx86_64-5.10.289.1486.sh
   ```
3. Execute this script as root

   ```
   sudo ./Xeroxv5Pkg-Debianx86_64-5.10.289.1486.sh
   ```
4. A GUI opens, accept conditions and wait.
5. When script stopped, launch as root the Xerox printer config interface

   ```
   sudo xeroxprtmgr
   ```
6. You can add your printer with this tool.

Note: I haven't found out how to set a printer that user can choose Colour or B&W, so I created 2 printers : 1 for Colour and 1 for B&W.

Now all that remains it to set the correct printer address, since the one that is created is `file:///dev/null`!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for this, it's available in one of my GitHub repositories.

https://github.com/georgerbr/someppdsifixed

Answer (score 0):

After running the "sh" file that you download from the xerox website, it looks like nothing has happened, but a new ppd file will be in etc/cups/ppd folder.  Choose that ppd file when installing the printer.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone (including myself) stumbles over this question, none of the answers work on current versions of Ubuntu.

A few years ago, I found a PPD that actually worked after slight adjustments. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/webmozart/30a8d132e37e3e270f4e36b36b556c8e

Save it as `Xerox-WorkCentre-6605DN.ppd` (or any other name) and select it when installing the printer.